# Хорошие уроки по Unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Посоветуйте пожалуйста хорошие уроки по созданию игр на Unity2d с использованием физики. Желательно на русском, но можно и на английском.

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @dIm0n Так пойдёт?

Comment: Лучшие уроки это документация?
https://docs.unity3d.com

Comment: Советую видео ютубера Graphical Design.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHr72IH-33mrD2h09MR3N3Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую Emerald Powder. Качество на высоте, все хорошо и отлично объясняет.
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6wnai488mwec_FUVfdl84w

Answer (score 0):

Уроками не обойтись, нужны курсы, и не один.

1. [Скриптинг](https://learn.unity.com/project/beginner-gameplay-scripting?uv=5.x&courseId=5c61706dedbc2a324a9b022d)

Курс уроков от `Unity Technologies` для начинающих.

2. [С#](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+c%23)

Нужно изучить основы языка (не забудьте познакомиться с `event` и `Action`).

Принципы: инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм !!!

3. [Паттерны проектирования](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/)

Нужны не все, для начала `Singleton` и `State`, но и с остальными ознакомиться.

---

И вы сможете начать писать игры.