# Нужно спавнить монетки в 2d игре Unity, подскажите что нужно добавить в скрипт

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class control : MonoBehaviour {

 public Sprite startBlock;
 public Sprite midBlock;
public Sprite endBlock;
public Sprite coino;
public float a = 45;
public float x;
public float y;
public float ay;
public float ax;
public float ca;
public float r;
 private int completeLevels = 0;

public void Start() {
  StartCoroutine(OnGeneratingRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator OnGeneratingRoutine() {

      Vector2 size = new Vector2(a, a);
Vector2 position = new Vector2(x, y);
Vector2 coinsize = new Vector2(ca,ca);

GameObject newBlock = new GameObject("Start block");
 newBlock.transform.position = position;
newBlock.transform.localScale = size;
newBlock.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(ax,ay);
newBlock.layer = 8;
SpriteRenderer renderer = newBlock.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

renderer.sprite = this.startBlock;


int count = this.completeLevels + 100;
/*for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
GameObject coin = new GameObject("coinblocj"); 
Vector2 coinpos = new Vector2(position.x, position.y + 3);
SpriteRenderer renderers = coin.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
coin.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = r;
coin.transform.localScale = coinsize;
coin.transform.position = coinpos;
renderers = coin.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
renderers.sprite = this.coino;
}*/
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

  newBlock = new GameObject("Middle block");

 renderer = newBlock.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

renderer.sprite = this.midBlock;
newBlock.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(ax,ay);

newBlock.layer = 8;
newBlock.transform.localScale = size;

position.x += size.x;
position.y += size.y * Random.Range(-1, 2);
 newBlock.transform.position = position;

 yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
 }
newBlock = new GameObject("End block");
renderer = newBlock.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
renderer.sprite = this.endBlock;
 newBlock.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(ax,ay);
newBlock.layer = 8;
 position.x += size.x;
position.y += size.y * Random.Range(-1, 2);
newBlock.transform.position = position;
 newBlock.transform.localScale = size;

yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
 }

public void CompleteLevel() {
this.completeLevels += 1;
StartCoroutine(OnGeneratingRoutine());
}

 }
```

Весь закоментированный код это мои попытки спавнить монетки, но если его раскоментировать спавняться только 3 блока земли. Код генератора уровня взят из интернета.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163588/Хорошие-уроки-по-unity2d

Comment: Я ж прошу ответ, а не ссылки на уроки кидать я и сам могу пойти разобраться, но это много времени поэтому прошу шарящих код откоректировать

Comment: Ответ - `Instantiate()`. Ищите в документации, читайте как работает эта функция и как им пользоваться.

Answer (score 0):

> Какого ___ вы называете переменные именами `a` `x` `y` `ay` `ax` `ca` `r`. Просто представьте, что кто-то будет читать ваш код! Он же сойдет с ума.

Теперь по вопросу: в целом ваш вопрос ищется в Яндексе за 20 секунд по запросу `Как создать объект в юнити из скрипта`. Получаем страницу документации под названием [создание и уничтожение объектов на сцене](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/CreateDestroyObjects.html). Также можно найти отдельные статьи по функции создания объекта [Instantiate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/net-NetworkInstantiate.html) и [Destroy()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html). Первая страница полностью на русском, вторые две - нет.

Ну а если вы не хотите ходить по ссылкам, напишу кратко:
функция Instantiate() - создает на сцене указанный в параметрах объект. Может принимать следующие наборы параметров:

1. `Instantiate(GameObject original)` - создает объект original
2. `Instantiate(GameObject original, GameObject parent)` - создает объект original, помещая его в родительский объект parent
3. `Instantiate(GameObject original, GameObject parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace)` - создавать объект в мировом пространстве (true) или учитывая позицию его родителя (false)
4. `Instantiate (Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)` - создает объект original в позиции position и с вращением rotation
5. `Instantiate (Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent)` - создает объект original в позиции position и с вращением rotation, помещая его в родительский объект parent

Comment: @ОлександрОдменович, если вам помогмой ответ, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку, тем самым приняв мой ответ. Иначе - можете задать вопросы - я отвечу